# Android NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, sockets, http, httpresponse

I got an `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` when I try to retreive JSON data from my PC-host, here is my code

```
public JSONObject getJSONObject(String url)
{
    Log.v("", "enter");
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    Log.v("", "httpclient");
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    Log.v("", "httppost");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    Log.v("", "setHeader");
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    HttpResponse response;
    try
    {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.v("", "response");
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Log.v("", "entity");
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            Log.v("", "inputStream");
            Log.v("", buildJSONString( inputStream ));
            return new JSONObject( buildJSONString( inputStream ) );
    }
}
```

my call from activity

```
JSONObject jObject = (new JSONParser(this))
                .getJSONObject("http://192.168.0.81:8080/content/test.json");
```

and my logcat

```
09-12 12:32:05.878: V/(11103): enter
09-12 12:32:05.878: V/(11103): httpclient
09-12 12:32:05.878: V/(11103): httppost
09-12 12:32:05.878: V/(11103): setHeader
09-12 12:32:05.878: W/System.err(11103): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1108)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:133)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:118)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:849)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:154)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:580)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:512)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:490)
09-12 12:32:05.888: W/System.err(11103):    at com.dwaik.jsonparser.JSONParser.getJSONObject(JSONParser.java:72)
```

it states that my exception is at `response = httpclient.execute(httppost);` 
I got internet permission , access to server actually I can download files from it within same app.
Any idea?

Comment: have you did this on UI Thread (MainThread), Use AsyncTask to hit the server

Comment: If you had bothered to Google for "NetworkOnMainThreadException" you would have found the answer in the first link returned. This question has been asked many times before.

Comment: thanks all works like charm +1 for all good answers

Comment: Always search first and then post questions Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are **not allowed to do network operations with the Main (UI) thread.**

There are several ways of using background threads.
I would recommend using **AsyncTask** since it has a nice structure which is easy to understand.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Here is an SO example also: [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Should be a lot more available on Google.

Comment: thanks +1 for good answer and accpeted for the links :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Android NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

*Because you are performing* `n/w operations` on `main Ui thread`

*Either Use* `AsyncTask` or `Thread`

*AsyncTask:*  [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
class myAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // Keep in mind You Can't Update UI Part here

              JSONObject jObject = (new JSONParser(this))
                .getJSONObject("http://192.168.0.81:8080/content/test.json");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Handle/Update UI Part
        }
    }
```

*Call it like*

```
new myAsync().execute();
```